# Send a file generated from table2excel.js using ajax to save it on server

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a HTML table from which i am generating a .xls file through Table2Excel.js plugin. I am trying to post this file to server so that i can save it at the server using php. I am trying to send the file in blob format, but my $_POST is returning empty. 
Heres my code for ajax:

```
  var blob = new Blob([e.format(fullTemplate, e.ctx)], { type: "application/vnd.ms-excel" });
            var dob = "okay lets check";
            window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
            link = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            a = document.createElement("a");
            a.download = getFileName(e.settings);
            a.href = link;
            document.getElementById("getPDF").value = link;
            document.body.appendChild(a);

            a.click();

            document.body.removeChild(a);
            var formdata = new FormData();
            formdata.append('excelFile', blob);
            $.ajax({
              url:'savetoserver.php',
              type:'post',
              data:formdata,
              processData: false,
              contentType: false,
            }).done(function (data){
              alert(data);
            }).fail(function (xhr, status, err) {
              alert(err);
            });
```

and php code is basically atm

```
<?php print_r($_POST); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$_FILES` in order to receive the file in PHP. here is an example PHP-script.

```
if (0 < $_FILES['excelFile']['error'])
    echo 'Error: ' . $_FILES['excelFile']['error'];
else
    move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['excelFile']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['excelFile']['name']);
```

Comment: i tried what you said, but it seems to be not working. The excel file is being dynamically generated.

Comment: @AdityaThakur are you sure `blob` is a file with content?